# React-router matches wrong component with similar match

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

So I am developing an app in react and have react router lib to show different possible URLs in my app. I have the following `routes`, defining which component will be rendered, depending on the URL:

```
<Route path={`/products/:address/:page`} component={Products} />
<Route path={`/products/:productId`} component={ProductDetails} />
<Route render={() => <NotFound/>}/>
```

The 1st one expects something like this: `/products/store/1` to match the products and show the products page.

The 2nd one expects something like this: `/products/5e996d123e1e0816242aed80` and shows the product details.

The 3rd one is a fallback UI, if nothing matches

My problem is, that if I am in the 1st URL and delete the page (1), eg `/products/store/`, react router gets confused and tries to match the 2nd route.

In both components, I load the params in`componentDidMount` like this:
`this.props.match.params.address`, `this.props.match.params.page` for the 1st component and `this.props.match.params.address` for the 2nd.

Ideally, I would like to render the 3rd route, if the 2nd argument of the 1st route is not present.

One possible solution would be to change the 2nd Route from `/products/:productId` to `/product/:productId`, so it won't get confused.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried with exact prop on route component?

Comment: Yeap, my first go was that, forgot to mention that. Didn't have any effect though.

Comment: I have the same question.